# Laravel where condition not working on query WITH relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a simple query that looks like this:

```
$category = Category::with('translation')
            ->with(['childCategories' => function ($query) {
                $query->active();
            }])
            ->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Scope and relation:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', 1);
}

public function childCategories()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\SupremeShop\Models\Category',
        'App\SupremeShop\Models\CategoryToCategory',
        'id_parent_category', //category_to_categories
        'id',  //categories
        'id',
        'id_category');  // category_to_categories.
}
```

So i am looking for category, some translations and child categories of given  "main" category. And query returns 15 child categories. But in query is scope that **should only take  active ones** and it's **not working correctly**. When i use dd it shows inactive child categories also. I've tried to remove scope and write simple WHERE but result was the same.

Have somebody any ides why condition is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the column is ambiguous since `Category` and its relation `childCategories` are both the same model and share the same table.

The `active()` scope is getting applied to the parent `Category` instead of the child `Categories`.

Try and see if this works

```php
$category = Category::from('categories as c')
                    ->with(['childCategories' => function ($query) {
                        $query->active();
                    }])
                    ->where('id', $id)->first();
```